# Return value before loading content from JSON in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a function in java script, that I used  it to take the JSON from my asp.net mvc controller, to display the item in my view :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var k = 0;
var record_count = 0;
var col_count = 3;
var row_count = record_count / col_count;
var str = "<table>";

function itemTemplate() {
 var url = '<%: Url.Content("~/") %>' + "ProductListing/AllProductListing/0";
 $.getJSON(url, function (product) {
      $.each(product.ja, function (index, value) {
       //append rows and column to my table by concat the string of 'str'
      });
 });
  str += '</table>';
  alert(str);
  return (str);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  alert(itemTemplate());
});
</script>
```

Problem : when I alert the function in `$(document).ready` function, first it is alert `<table></table>` and then continue to alert the full string that I concatenate it in my `$.getJSON` function. So the function is return before taking JSON.

Anyone have any idea about it?
Thanks.

Comment: You are doing AJAX, so you have to update the table, all inside the function that works with the received data i.e. the function that to pass to getJSON.

Comment: Do you mean, I have to separate `itemTemplate` into two different functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting `async` to false, then make your `$.getJSON` call

**Code:**

```
jQuery.ajax({async : false});
$.getJSON( ... );
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

**Note: As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false is deprecated.**

**Alternate Solution**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var k = 0;
var record_count = 0;
var col_count = 3;
var row_count = record_count / col_count;
//var str = "<table>";

function itemTemplate(callback) {
 var url = '<%: Url.Content("~/") %>' + "ProductListing/AllProductListing/0";
 $.getJSON(url, callback);
  //str += '</table>';
  //alert(str);
  //return (str);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  itemTemplate(function (product) {
      var str = "<table>";
      $.each(product.ja, function (index, value) {
       //append rows and column to my table by concat the string of 'str'
      });
      str += "</table>";
      alert(str);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still got the same problem.

Comment: Nothing different when I put the `async:false`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's how ajax works, the `$.getJSON` starts an asynchronous call to the server, so you will hit the next lines before the ajax call is completed. You should create all of the table HTML inside the callback for the `getJSON`

```
function itemTemplate() {
 var url = '<%: Url.Content("~/") %>' + "ProductListing/AllProductListing/0";
 $.getJSON(url, function (product) {
      var html = "<table>";
      $.each(product.ja, function (index, value) {
       //append rows and column to my table by concat the string of 'str'
      });
      html += "</table>";
      // now append html to the DOM
 });
}
```

the function will return before you get the data back from the server, so anything you want to do with the data returned from the server has to be inside the callback of the `.getJSON`

Comment: Do you mean, I have to append my string to html elements in each condition?

Comment: Indeed, the itemTemplate function will not return anything... so doing alert on the return won't show you the correct results, what ever you want to do with the data from the server has to be done inside the getJSON callback function

Answer (score 1):

Ajax requests to a server are **asynchronous**. This means, the client computer says: *Go forth and do something at that 3rd party server. And when you have an answer (aka, a response) then tell me and i'll deal with it.*

So .. lets wire that JQuery code to do -exactly- that...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Just call this method, on load. 
        // (yuck, but i'm following your code)...
        itemTemplate(); 
    });

    function itemTemplate() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ProductListing/AllProductListing/0",
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                // Handle success. like .. append data, etc.
                //.....
                alert("whatever");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // Handle the error. Don't forget you can access
                // data from the response (aka. the jqXHR)...
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

The trick here was to wire up the `success:` and the `error:` callback's.

Once in there, you can do whatever you want, etc.

Try putting a break point in there and seeing the values :)

Reference: [jQuery.ajax() doco's](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

`$.getJSON` executes asynchronously which means that as soon as it fires off the request the function invocation is considered complete and the JavaScript engine moves on to the next line of code: `str += '</table>'`.

You get two alerts because you invoke the `alert` function within your `itemTemplate` function which itself is invoked to return a value for the `alert` function call made within `$(document).ready`. Did you mean to call `alert` twice?

In any case it seems that your intention as far as building `str` is to close out the table tag after the completion of `$.each` so...

```
var k = 0,
    record_count = 0,
    col_count = 3,
    row_count = record_count / col_count,
    str = '<table>';

function itemTemplate() {
    var url = '<%: Url.Content("~/") %>' + "ProductListing/AllProductListing/0";
    $.getJSON(url, function (product) {
        $.each(product.ja, function (index, value) {
            //append rows and column to my table by concat the string of 'str'
        });
        str += '</table>';
        alert(str);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    itemTemplate();
});
```